# Transform children objects to parent object, grouped by parent

Tags: rx-java

I have the following classes:

```
class Parent {
   List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
   Parent parent;
}
```

Initially i have a list of `Parent`s. I want to do the following:

- transform list of `Parents` to a merged list of `Child`ren
- filter the list of `Child`ren
- transform back to list of `Parent`s, whose `children` list only contains the corresponding filtered `Child`ren

For example:

```
[Parent1 {[child1, child2]},
 Parent2 {[child3, child4]}]
```

Filter all `Child`ren with even index:

```
[Parent1 {[child2]},
 Parent2 {[child4]}]
```

Currently i am doing this:

```
List<Parent> allParents = ...
allParents.flatMap(Observable::from)
        .map(parent -> parent.children)
        .flatMap(Observable::from)
        .filter(child -> child.index % 2 == 0)
```

But i do not know how could i transform back to the list of desired `Parent`s. Please not the `children` list can be modified in `Parent` objects, but i want to same `Parent` objects originally coming in the list. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map it back and use distinct:

```
...
.map(child -> child.parent)
.distinct()
...
```

**Update:**

If you are using Java 8 then you can apply the filter function to the children list directly and remove all that's unnecessary:

```
Observable.from(parents)
.doOnNext(p -> p.children.removeIf(c -> c.index % 2 != 0))
.filter(p -> !p.children.isEmpty())
.subscribe(...)
```

**Update 2:**

```
Observable.from(parents)
.flatMapIterable(p -> {
    List<Child> cs = new ArrayList<>(p.children);
    p.children.clear();
    return cs;
})
.filter(c -> c.index % 2 == 0)
.doOnNext(c -> c.parent.children.add(c))
.map(c -> c.parent);
.distinct()
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: The problem with this that the `Parent.children` reference will not be updated.

Comment: I have a requirement that i have to apply the filter as i wrote in the OP, so i cannot call `removeIf`. (Of course my real problem is harder.)

Comment: So you need the original Parent objects with trimmed children without chainging the children array?

Comment: I want to change the children array, as your current code does. But to apply my already written filters, I must do it by transforming to list of child, and apply the filters to that list, then transform back to parent list with the children arrays updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I was using [this](https://gist.github.com/WonderCsabo/132c1340aac48a70a436) method which also produced the same result, but was much slower and more hackish.